# Firebase Firestore: Append/Remove items from document array

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to append/remove items from an array inside of a Firestore Document but every time the entire array is replaced instead of the new value being appended. I have tried both of the following:

```
batch.setData(["favorites": [user.uid]], forDocument: bookRef, options: SetOptions.merge())

batch.updateData(["favorites": [user.uid]], forDocument: bookRef)
```

I know that instead of an array I can use an object/dictionary but that would mean storing additional data that is irrelevant (such as the key), all I need is the ID's stored inside the array. Is this something that is currently possible in Firestore?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, nowadays it is possible. With latest updates `db.collection.updateData`
method actually appends new item to array instead of replacing it.
Example usage can be found in [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

If you need to do it manually, you can use

```
FieldValue.arrayUnion([user.uid])
```

Comment: Just used this in my project only worked after adding in the '.updateData([
    
    "name" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([self.colleagueName])'

Comment: I am trying to remove a value from array on a document as:    document.updateData([
            "memberIds": FieldValue.arrayRemove(memberIds)
            ]) . But each time I try to access the value of this array, then deleted value is also present in the data.

Answer (score 22):

Update elements in an array

If your document contains an array field, you can use arrayUnion() and arrayRemove() to add and remove elements. arrayUnion() adds elements to an array but only elements not already present. arrayRemove() removes all instances of each given element.

```
let washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC")

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.updateData([
    "regions": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["greater_virginia"])
])

// Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.updateData([
    "regions": FieldValue.arrayRemove(["east_coast"])
])
```

[See documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)

Answer (score 2):

Nope. This isn't possible.

Arrays tend to be problematic in an environment like Cloud Firestore where many clients could theoretically append or remove elements from an array at the same time -- if instructions arrive in a slightly different order, you could end up with out-of-bounds errors, corrupted data, or just a really bad time. So you either need to use a dictionary (where you can specify individual keys) or replace the entire array.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for confirming/clarifying Todd!

Comment: @LucaVentura you can see why "Arrays are evil" in this firebase blog article https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html :)

Comment: @cutiko thanks for the link. Using a dictionary in my case worked out better anyways as I wouldn't be able to easily remove a value without accessing it from the key :)