# Removing an array item from Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I've spent days researching this including various answers like: [Firebase Firestore: Append/Remove items from document array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943092/firebase-firestore-append-remove-items-from-document-array)
but can't work out how to actually get this working.

I have two structs:

```
struct TestList : Codable {
    var title : String
    var color: String
    var number: Int
}

struct TestGroup: Codable {
    var items: [TestList]
}
```

I am able to add data using `FieldValue.arrayUnion`:

```
@objc func addNewItem() {
        
        let testList = TestList(title: "Testing", color: "blue", number: Int.random(in: 1..<999))
        let docRef = FirestoreReferenceManager.simTest.document("abc")
        docRef.updateData([
            "items" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([["title":testList.title,
                                             "color":testList.color,
                                             "number":testList.number]])
        ])
    }
```

The above works as reflected in the Firestore dashboard:

[image]

But if I try and remove one of the items in the array, it just doesn't work.

```
@objc func removeItem() {
 let docRef = FirestoreReferenceManager.simTest.document("abc")
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            do {
                let retrievedTestGroup = try document?.data(as: TestGroup.self)
                let retrievedTestItem = retrievedTestGroup?.items[1]
                guard let itemToRemove = retrievedTestItem else { return }
                docRef.updateData([
                    "items" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([["title" : itemToRemove.title,
                                                      "color" : itemToRemove.color,
                                                      "number" : itemToRemove.number]])
                ]) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("successfully deleted")
                }
                }

            } catch {

            }
        }
}
```

I have printed the `itemToRemove` to the log to check that it is correct and it is.  But it just doesn't remove it from Firestore.  There is no error returned, yet the `"successfully deleted"` is logged.

Note the above is test code as I've simplified what I actually need just for testing purposes because I can't get this working.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `arrayRemove` to remove items from arrays.

```
@objc func removeItem() {
    let docRef = FirestoreReferenceManager.simTest.document("abc")
    
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        do {
            let retrievedTestGroup = try document?.data(as: TestGroup.self)
            let retrievedTestItem = retrievedTestGroup?.items[1]
            guard let itemToRemove = retrievedTestItem else { return }
            docRef.updateData([
                "items" : FieldValue.arrayRemove([["title" : itemToRemove.title,
                                                  "color" : itemToRemove.color,
                                                  "number" : itemToRemove.number]])
            ]) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("successfully deleted")
                }
            }
            
        } catch {
            
        }
    }
}
```

I've encountered situations where this straightforward approach didn't work because the item was a complex object, in which case I first had to query for the item from Firestore and plug that instance into `arrayRemove()` to remove it.

The reason your approach doesn't have any side effects is because arrays in Firestore are not like arrays in Swift, they are hybrids of arrays and sets. You can initialize an array in Firestore with duplicate items but you cannot append arrays using `arrayUnion()` with duplicate items. Trying to append a duplicate item using `arrayUnion()` will silently fail, such as in your case.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually had a cut and paste error here.  This seems to be working if I explicitly list each field value, e.g. "title" and then its corresponding value.  This seems to be the only way to get this to work.  I tried using a TestList object in FieldValue.arrayRemove but it seems to not like that

Comment: @Anthony it's not the only way. The other way is to get the item from Firestore (in or out of a transaction) and plug that into `arrayRemove()`.

Comment: I was having issues trying to get that to work which is I reverted to the above.  I'll try it again and if I can't get it, I'll post another question.  Thank you heaps.

Comment: Worked out where the problem occurs and it's when there is a date property in the struct/object.  I've posted a new question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733560/removing-an-array-item-from-firestore-not-working-when-array-contains-date If you have any ideas, I'd really appreciate it.